# Split string without remove seperator and also keep seperator at start position?

Tags: c#, string

Here my string.

```
string content =    
  @"[INFO ] | 2016-11-28 10:56:19.68 | level to ""Info""
    [INFO ] | 2016-11-28 10:56:56.93 | to ""Info""
    [DEBUG ] | 2016-11-28 10:56:56.93 | been initialized successfully.
    [INFO ] | 2016-11-28 11:01:14.05 | to ""Info""
    [ERROR] | 2016-11-28 11:01:14.05 | initialized successfully."
```

this is my string content and i want to split my string using following separator `[INFO ]`, `[ERROR ]`, `[DEBUG ]` but I don't want to remove that word I used regex positive look back but they append separator `enter code here` at last 
i want separator at original position:

I want splited string like this

```
      1=>[INFO ] | 2016-11-28 10:56:19.68 | level to "Info"
      2=>[INFO ] | 2016-11-28 10:56:56.93 | to "Info"
      3=>[DEBUG ] | 2016-11-28 10:56:56.93 | been initialized successfully.
      4=>[INFO ] | 2016-11-28 11:01:14.05 | to "Info"
      5=>[ERROR] | 2016-11-28 11:01:14.05 | initialized successfully."
```

Comment: *"here my string"* How do you feel about posting a compilable `string` ? Since `string content=` imply's that its in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shamelessly started with @DmitryBychenko answer and tried to improve it.

If you want to support multiline entries and more accurate matching of the exact separators `"[INFO ]"`, `"[DEBUG ]"` and `"[ERROR ]"`, you can use the following regex:

```
var pattern = @"(\[INFO \]|\[DEBUG \]|\[ERROR \]).+?(?=\[INFO \]|\[DEBUG \]|\[ERROR \]|\z)";

var matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(content, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline)
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select((match, index) => index + "=>" + match.Groups[0].Value.Trim());
```

It starts a match with the specified separators (the `"(\[INFO \]|\[DEBUG \]|\[ERROR \])"` part of `pattern`) and continues to match until the next separator is reached (this is the `".+?(?=\[INFO \]|\[DEBUG \]|\[ERROR \]|\z)"` part).

This transforms

```
@"[INFO ] | 2016-11-28 10:56:19.68 | level to ""Info""
[INFO ] | 2016-11-28 10:56:56.93 | to ""Info""
[DEBUG ] | 2016-11-28 10:56:56.93 | been initialized successfully.
[INFO ] | 2016-11-28 11:01:14.05 | to ""Info""
More info in second line
[IRRELEVANT TAG] | Noone knows what this is | ""Whatever""
[ERROR ] | 2016-11-28 11:01:14.05 | initialized successfully."
```

into

```
0=>[INFO ] | 2016-11-28 10:56:19.68 | level to "Info"
1=>[INFO ] | 2016-11-28 10:56:56.93 | to "Info"
2=>[DEBUG ] | 2016-11-28 10:56:56.93 | been initialized successfully.
3=>[INFO ] | 2016-11-28 11:01:14.05 | to "Info"
More info in second line
[IRRELEVANT TAG] | Noone knows what this is | "Whatever"
4=>[ERROR ] | 2016-11-28 11:01:14.05 | initialized successfully.
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *splitting*, I suggest *matching* with a help of *regular expressions*:

```
  string content = 
    @"[INFO ] | 2016-11-28 10:56:19.68 | level to ""Info""
      [INFO ] | 2016 - 11 - 28 10:56:56.93 | to ""Info""
      [DEBUG ] | 2016 - 11 - 28 10:56:56.93 | been initialized successfully.
      [INFO ] | 2016-11-28 11:01:14.05 | to ""Info""
      [ERROR] | 2016-11-28 11:01:14.05 | initialized successfully.";

   // square brackets []
   // with uppercase text or spaces within it
   // followed by any characters
   // up to the end of line or end of the entire text
  string pattern = @"(\[[A-Z ]+\].+?)(?:\z|\n|\r)";

  var result = Regex
    .Matches(content, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline)
    .OfType<Match>()
  // .Select(match => match.Groups[1].Value}) // if you want just a match
    .Select((match, index) => $"{index + 1}=>{match.Groups[1].Value}");
  // .ToArray(); // <- you may want to materialize the result into, say, an array
```

Test:

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
 1=>[INFO ] | 2016-11-28 10:56:19.68 | level to "Info"
 2=>[INFO ] | 2016 - 11 - 28 10:56:56.93 | to "Info"
 3=>[DEBUG ] | 2016 - 11 - 28 10:56:56.93 | been initialized successfully.
 4=>[INFO ] | 2016-11-28 11:01:14.05 | to "Info"
 5=>[ERROR] | 2016-11-28 11:01:14.05 | initialized successfully.
```